# Hi, Im new to vb.net. I imported data from excel to datagrid, Now i Need help to merge all rows before each empty row in the datagrid

Tags: datagridview, formatting

[Imported Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vsgh.png)

I imported above data from excel to datagrid, Now i Need help to merge all rows before each empty row in the datagrid using an array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Description is on two different rows while the unit and quantity is on the same row. I need to merge description from the two rows  and delete one row. Below is my data.
  
DESCRIPTION                                                                          UNIT QUANTITY
The JBCC Preliminaries Code 2022, July 2022 Edition for use  100
 with the JBCC Principle  
  
Pricing of preliminaries  Heading 3 
  
Items not priced in these Preliminaries shall be deemed to be  2